# Apache brooklyn blueprint using entity

Tags: apache, brooklyn

I am trying to create an application from available entities from Apache Brooklyn. 
My blueprint is :

```
name: Tomcat3
location: 
  jclouds:....
services:
- type: brooklyn.entity.webapp.tomcat.TomcatServer
  name: tomcat
  provisioning.properties:
    minRam: 1024mb
    minCores: 2
    minDisk: 1024
  extraSshPublicKeyUrls:
  - https://.............../file.pub
```

This creates an instance with Tomcat and the status shows as 'Running' and the service status is up . But when I connect to the URL of the tomcat application I cannot see Tomcat running there .  What am I missing here ?

Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that no WAR file was specified as root WAR and therefore nothing was visible on tomcat url.

Solution is to add a `wars.root` configuration entry to the service configuration portion of the blueprint:

```
services:
- type: brooklyn.entity.webapp.tomcat.TomcatServer
  name: tomcat
  wars.root:
    http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=io/brooklyn/example/brooklyn-example-hello-world-sql-webapp/0.6.0/brooklyn-example-hello-world-sql-webapp-0.6.0.war
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many layers of network/firewall in between you and Tomcat's port. Some likely possibilities include:

- Is it failing to connect, or is it giving a 404? If a 404, then is it just that there is no WAR deployed?
- Is iptables running on the VM, locking down those ports (if so, try with the location config `openIptables: true`).
- Is the cloud giving public IPs (e.g. in vCloud Director you'd need to set up NAT rules using Brooklyn's "advanced networking" configuration).

There are many possibilities and debugging options. Suggest you jump on the Apache Brooklyn mailing list or IRC if it's still a problem (https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html).